# how to make mdl-badge data-badge content dynamic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I have created a mdl-badge with data-badge class to add a alert icon on my page. How can I dynamically change the data-badge data (i.e. rather than hard coded 5) in my controller so the displayed number corresponds to number of alerts reported by backend server. Doing {{alertcount}} does not seem to work. The html is:

```
            <a class="mdl-badge mdl-badge--overlap mdl-badge--no-background" data-badge="5" href="#monitor"><i id="ttalert" class="material-icons">messages</i></a>
            <div class="mdl-tooltip" for="ttalert">Alerts</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so this is what I have done and it seems to work:

```
            alerticon = document.getElementById('alertbadge');
            alerticon.setAttribute('data-badge', alertcount);
```